# How to make phpStorm know about static referenced class implementation?

Tags: phpstorm

I have written this method in a parent class in order to be able to get instances of children too.

```
   /** @return static */
        public static function getInstance()
        {
            /** @var $instance static */
            static $instance = false;
            if (!$instance) {
                $instance = new static();
            }
            return $instance;
        }
```

When I get the instance, **PhpStorm doesn't know about child class implementation** (methods, constants, etc). **How can I tell him about them**?

In snippet I am suggesting @return and @var as methods that work in contexts that don't imply static refference.

Comment: Which version of PhpStorm are you using? And how do you call the static function for a child class?

Comment: I call it like Child::getInstance(). This is what you've asked?

Comment: AFAIK `@return static` did not worked in v5. But there were big improvements made in **v6** in this regard and this one should be working OK now. Try it (it can be installed and run alongside v5 -- just make copy of project settings (.idea subfolder) if you want to keep working in v5 later)

Comment: I tested this in 6.0.2 and it works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@return static` does work in PhpStorm 6 (I tested in 6.0.2.) So you should upgrade to the latest version if you want to use this feature.